# How to iterate through sql table and fetch distinct values from another into a result table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of tables that control a client's budget in a monthly basis. This are the relationships created:

[image]

Right now, I'm trying to create a procedure that will bring the distinct "rubro" field from the table [dbo].[Ppto_IngresosRubros] according to the user that is currently logged ([dbo].[Clientes_Usuarios]) And the budgets that he/she has created in [dbo].[Ppto_Master]

The [dbo].[Ppto_IngresosRubros] has the following data stored in it:

```
ID    IdPpto    Rubro
3     4         Ventas desarrollo tecnológico
4     4         Ventas diseño estratégico
5     5         Ventas desarrollo tecnológico
5     5         Ventas diseño estratégico
```

The table [dbo].[Ppto_Master] has the following data:

```
ID    IdCliente    IdModulo    FechaPpto    
4     1            1           2018-01-01
5     1            1           2018-02-01
```

The code I have so far will bring me the desired result but in separeted set of tables, so I can't use it to populate a repeater (in the project's view - ASP.Net WebForms VB):

[image]

And what I need is:

```
Rubro
Ventas desarrollo tecnológico
Ventas diseño estratégico
```

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @usuario varchar(max) = 'eduardo@conceptod.co'

DECLARE @idcliente int
SET @idcliente =
(
    SELECT
        [W1].[ID] 
    FROM [dbo].[Clientes_Info_W1] [W1]
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[Clientes_Usuarios] [U]
        ON [W1].[ID] = [U].[IdCliente]
    WHERE   
        ([U].[CorreoElectronico] = @usuario)  
)

DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @idppto int;
BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
    (
        SELECT 
            [M].[ID]
        FROM [dbo].[Ppto_Master] [M]
        WHERE
            ([M].[IdCliente] = @idcliente) 

    )
    OPEN @MyCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
    INTO @idppto

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT([I].[Rubro]) 
        FROM [dbo].[Ppto_IngresosRubros] [I]
        WHERE
            ([I].[ID] = @idppto)
    )
      FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
      INTO @idppto
    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```

Help! Thanks!

Comment: I question whether you need to be using so many cursors here.  Sample data and the expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Well, your comment made me thought of another approach. I achieved it by using joins. Thanks

Comment: @epaezr . . . You should close the question if it is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved through a Join:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Ppto_IngresosRubros_Rubros_Tips_IdCliente]
(
    @usuario varchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @idcliente int
SET @idcliente =
(
    SELECT
        [W1].[ID] 
    FROM [dbo].[Clientes_Info_W1] [W1]
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[Clientes_Usuarios] [U]
        ON [W1].[ID] = [U].[IdCliente]
    WHERE   
        ([U].[CorreoElectronico] = @usuario)  
)

SELECT
    DISTINCT TOP(5) ([I].[Rubro]) AS [Rubro]
FROM [dbo].[Ppto_IngresosRubros] [I]
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Ppto_Master] [M]
    ON [I].[IdPpto] = [M].[ID] 
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Clientes_Info_W1] [W1]
    ON [M].[IdCliente] = [W1].[ID]
WHERE
    ([W1].[ID] = @idcliente);
END
GO
```

Thanks!